# Get itemView at specific position in adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a problem with get itemView in my adapter for preselect element in RecyclerView.
In my **activity** I have:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activityRecicler);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new CustomRecycleAdapter(array, ReceiptNewActivity.this, arrayJson);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    int adapterLength = adapter.getItemCount();
    int length = arrayJson.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<adapterLength; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
            try {
                if(adapter.getItem(i).getInt("id") == arrayJson.getJSONObject(j).getInt("id")){

                    int value= arrayJson.getJSONObject(j).getInt("value");

                    float valueFloat = (float) value/250;
                    String valueString = String.valueOf(value);

                    //function in adapter for selected
                    adapter.setSelected(i, valueFloat);


                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                    View v= viewHolder.itemView;

                    adapter.setRowData(v, valueString);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that 
`RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);` return always null.
So How Can get itemView for position?

Comment: You do this right after you have set the adapter. I can imagine that this doesn't work because your `ViewHolder`s are not created yet. Check if `onBindViewHolder` is already called to be sure.

Comment: Hi.  Are you trying to set data of the RecyclerView from outside the CustomRecycleAdapter class, or am I interpreting your code wrong?

Comment: Hi Lev, yes, It is a bad practice or create a problem? I do this (adapter.setSelected) because I want keep what element is selected in adapter.

I have delete SetRowData and put in Onbind in adapter

Comment: Yes 0xDEADc0DE, the answer is a mixed of your comment and @Lev comment, I have put setRowData, in my Adapter onBindViewHolder and it work.

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, The Adapter is there for populating, setting data of your RecyclerView. You should do all the data setting inside the adapter code,  onBindViewHolder is the place you should do that.

Comment: Ah, 30 seconds late. Glad to be of service :)

Comment: yes! :) Thankyou lev and 0xDEADC0DE, The answer is a mixed of yours comments, I have put setRowData, in my Adapter onBindViewHolder and it work. I'm a chicken. thankyou

Comment: You can check this better implementation tutorial http://wiki.workassis.com/android-recyclerview-example/